# Python : Need to dynamically pass the data while sending request.post command

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Background :

> I am trying to send post request to API and in code I need to send the data.

Problem :

> I need to fetch data from a file and put into name and subnet field

expected output should be

```
data = '{ "name": "1.1.1.1", "subnet": "1.1.1.1/24", "eonId": 3 "environment": "PROD" }'
```

Now above data looks like dict but there its wrap with '' so how should I pass the data.

```
import requests
headers = {

    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    'Accept': 'application/json',
}
data = '{ "name": "x.x.x.x", "subnet": "y.y.y.y", "eonId": 3 "environment": "PROD" }'
response = requests.post('https://example.com, headers=headers, data=data, auth=('', ''))
```

Comment: where does this `data` comes ? if you write it yourself, remove the single quotes

Comment: Does the file content is what is between the single quotes ?

Comment: As others have said the format of the file is important here. If you can, set up the data file as a standard json or yaml file, then use python's `json` library or `pyYAML` to load the data as a dict. I think most of your issues can be resolved if you remember that (as long as you're dealing with simple data) python dicts can be loaded and dumped to JSON strings very easily.

Answer (score 0):

To make a Json request to the server, simply create a standard python dictionary and put required values there.

Use the `json=` parameter instead of `data=`. If server returns Json response, use `.json()` method to parse it.

For example:

```py
import requests

# load these parameters from file:
name = "1.1.1.1"
subnet = "1.1.1.1/24"

# create payload dictionary
payload = {
  "name": name, 
  "subnet": subnet, 
  "eonId": 3, 
  "environment": "PROD"
}
headers = {"User-Agent": "my-user-agent"}

# use json= parameter to pass the payload:
response = requests.post(
    "https://example.com", headers=headers, json=payload
).json()

print(response)
```